# Wordpress wpbakery bouton ligntbox

Tags: wordpress, lightbox, wpbakery

I want to integrate lightbox with wpbakery button i tried with a lot of plugins without success any one have a solution for that.
Thanks lot.

i tried with this lightbox plugins :
"Simple Lightbox," "FooBox," or "Responsive Lightbox & Gallery."